# AngularJS Controller Inheritance and Order of Execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance

I'm working in Angular with parent/child Controller inheritance and am encountering some behavior that I do not understand.

Basically, I set a property on an object in a parent Controller, and set it to a different value in the child Controller.  I output the value that was set in the parent Controller *before* the code in the child Controller should run.  However, I am seeing that the child Controller code has already run and set the value.

**Parent.Controller.js**

```
testapp.controller('ParentController', function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.myValue = 'Primitive value, defined in ParentController';
    $scope.myObject = {
      value: "Object property value, defined in ParentController"
    }
  } 

  $scope.init();
});
```

**Child.Controller.js**

```
testapp.controller('ChildController', function($scope) {
    $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.myValue = 'Primitive value, set in ChildController';
    $scope.myObject.value = "Object property value, set in ChildController";
  } 

  $scope.init();
});
```

**HTML Template**

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController" class="outer">
  1. Primitive value on scope: <span style="font-weight:bold">{{myValue}}</span>
  <br/>2. Object value on scope: <span style="font-weight:bold">{{myObject.value}}</span>
  <p>
    <div ng-controller="ChildController" class="inner">
      3. Primitive value on scope: <span style="font-weight:bold">{{myValue}}</span>
      <br/>4. Object value on scope: <span style="font-weight:bold">{{myObject.value}}</span>
    </div>
  <p>
  5. Primitive value on scope: <span style="font-weight:bold">{{myValue}}</span>
  <br/>6. Object value on scope: <span style="font-weight:bold">{{myObject.value}}</span>      
</div>
```

I would have expected #2 to show the value of the object that was defined by the Parent Controller, since the Child Controller should not yet have executed (the `ng-controller` directive for the ChildController is a couple lines south of this).

**Here is a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BYrZevmONZqUk4C1Hb2R?p=preview)**

If anyone could help me understand this behavior, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks,

Philip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter which controller is executed when: since the scope is inherited between the two controllers, so do the `myObject` variable.

Hence when the child controller updates `myObject.value`, it is using the *same* `myObject` than its parent controller, so you see the same value in both places in your HTML.

That is expected and often wanted. If you don't want the child controller to affect its parent, you should define a new object on that child:

```
testapp.controller('ChildController', function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.myValue = 'Primitive value, set in ChildController';
    $scope.myChildObject =  {value: "Object property value, set in ChildController"};
  } 
});
```

PS: If you add a `console.log` in both parent and child `init` functio, you will see that the parent controller is indeed read before the child one.

Answer (score 1):

When the value is changed later on, the dynamic binding also changes the first display of the variable.

Since no myObject is defined in the child scope, the one in the parent scope is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Has nothing to do with execution order but with prototypal inheritance.

Primitives don't have inheritance but objects do.

Primitive example

```
var a="foo";
var b = a; //"foo"
a="some value"
alert(b) // is still "foo"
```

`b` is assigned value that  `a`  had at the time of assignment only

object example

```
var a={x:'foo'};
var b = a; //  {x:'foo'}
a.x="a new value";
alert(b.x) // also changed to "a new value"
```

`a` and `b` are references to the same object

What you are seeing is the primitives don't bind to the parent but the object does ...as to be expected.

The childscope primitives will have values assigned from the parent based on what they are at the moment they are assigned. After that changes to either variable will be independent of the source or child

The objects are still references and changes made anywhere to any individual reference will be reflected in all references